# How to run your app on Kubernetes through a Jenkins build/post build step

Tags: plugins, jenkins, kubernetes

I tried looking for a Jenkins plugin (like AWS codeDeploy) so that I could deploy my application to a Kubernetes cluster. So far, I have been successful at pushing it to a Docker registry and adding some command line build steps to deploy to Kubernetes.
Looking at the CloudBees announcement [this seems possible](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2015/07/orchestrating-deployments-with-jenkins.html)

Installing the Kubernetes plugin gave me errors...I can attach a screenshot if that helps ...
Also it seems like this plugin allows you to run slaves in Docker containers not deploy your own app.

After looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFCSSiT-UUQ)
, it seemed I could accomplish this
using the `withKubernetes` workflow stage...

However adding that line to my workflow script gives me the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method withKubernetes found among [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, error, fileExists, git, input, load, mail, node, parallel, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:107)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:112)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:123)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:17)
    at Unknown.Unknown(Unknown)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:69)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor290.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:40)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:145)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:271)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:180)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:178)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I ended up using bash commands as well to push builds to k8s from Jenkins.  Curious on whether you used the rolling-update with the template argument?  I wasn't sure what it's for, but it sounded to me like I could feed it a Go template and possibly replace versions or any other placeholders with info from the last build.  I also had to write bash to pull the current active rc name to do the rolling update.  Wonky at best.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jenkins Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) is (so far) only to run slaves dynamically in a Kubernetes cluster

There's not a lot about deploying from Jenkins to Kubernetes, maybe this post [Continuous Delivery Pipelines with Fabric8 and Jenkins on OpenShift](https://medium.com/fabric8-io/create-and-explore-continuous-delivery-pipelines-with-fabric8-and-jenkins-on-openshift-661aa82cb45a) helps

Comment: Yes, that is part of the workflow plugin where as per the demo by kohsuke@, which I was trying to get working ...